# Running python files by double click but there is IDLE mismatch

Tags: python, python-idle

I have Python 3.7.4 installed on Windows 10. For some reasons, my "Edit with Python" option doesn't show up when I right click a Python script. So I made "idle.bat" as the default app to run Python scripts from the installed location "C:\Users\ns200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37". Now when I double click the Python Script, it runs and IDLE 3.7.1 (see picture) shows up with my code. Now when I execute the code, I get "ModuleNotFoundError" though I have all the modules installed(installed using pip3 function for IDLE 3.7.4)

[image: IDLE 3.7.1]

If I open IDLE manually, Python 3.7.4 shell runs and I need to open the script by going to file, open ,choose the file location and IDLE 3.7.4 shows up (see picture). When I execute the script this time, it runs with no errors (as all modules are already installed for 3.7.4).

[image: Python 3.7.4 shell]

I don't know why there is an IDLE mismatch here. How can I run IDLE 3.7.4 every time after double clicking the python script with no module error?

Comment: Select a default app associated with .py. You can do this in your windows settings under default apps -> select default app per filte type. A complete removal and reinstall of the latest python will also probably work (be sure to remove all versions if you try this.).

Comment: You have multiple Python interpreters installed and your `pip3` is pointing towards one of them. In your IDLE you can see somewhere in the project settings where your second Python interpreter is located. This will be a different path from `C:\Users\ns200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`. You need to fix one of the paths to have a consistent behavior, preferablly the one that matches with your `pip3`

Comment: There is no much difference between 3.7.1 and 3.7.4 better migrate all to 3.7.4 and uninstall 3.7.1......

Comment: @tjallo If I select the default Python app, I don't see the code running , it just executes. I want to see the code in IDLE first.

Comment: @TinNguyen Can you exactly specify where I can get that setting? I see Path Browser in File? Is it what you're pointing to ?

Comment: @VigneshRajendran How do I uninstall 3.7.1 specifically? If I uninstall from C Panel, everything will wipe.

Comment: Go to Control Panel, and check for python 3.7.1 and uninstall it

Comment: @VigneshRajendran There are only 2 files in control panel. One is Python 3.7.4(64bit) and the other is Python Launcher

Comment: @VipulPriyadarshi I know this isn't your question, but maybe look into other code editors like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python). They are much more powerful and have beautiful support for python built-in (in addition to the many extensions).

Comment: @tjallo That would be my last choice if this isn't fixed.

Comment: go to cmd and type where python, it will give all python in your PC like below  C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran>where python
C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
C:\SVN\CKMotorData\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe

Comment: Gives me two locations:
C:\Users\ns200>where python
C:\Users\ns200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
C:\Users\ns200\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
I don't see any other file in other location except "python3.exe" and "python.exe"

Comment: This is certainly not a batch-file issue, it is an OS/Software issue and as such is off topic on StackOverflow. I have removed the invalid [[tag:batch-file]] tag, and voted to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

you have selected the idle.bat inside py 3.7.1 , Select the idle.bat which is inside python 3.7.4 , your problem will be solved.

```
python37.4/lib/sitepackages/idlelib/Idle.bat
```

Approximate path above

Comment: I see only one location which is "C:\Users\ns200\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37" where I'm already pointing to. No other location is present.

Comment: mine looks like this "C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat" and "C:\Users\vignesh.rajendran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat" as i have two python inside my username, check outside of appdate  if you installed for all users